# Imagemagick parsing s3 image for modulation

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, aws-sdk

I'm running an express app, which is processing some image data. One of the tasks is to modulate a mask area. Im using [gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) module's Imagemagick subclass to parse and process the image. The modulation does work correctly when I am using the local files demo.png and demo_mask.png, but when I'm using the same image files downloaded from a s3 bucket, the modulation does not work.

Error

> Stream yields empty buffer ...

Download Image function

```
myBucket.getObject({
  Key    : "correct_src_key",
},(err, downloadData) => {
  return downloadData;
});
```

Code

```
    var gm = require('gm').subClass({
      imageMagick: true
    });

    ...

    gm(demo_download_data.Body)
    .mask(demo_mask_download_data.Body)
    .modulate(...)
    .toBuffer("PNG",function(err, buffer){ ... })
```

**debugger demo_download_data properties:**

> AcceptRange="bytes"  Body=Uint8Array[250830] ContentType="JPG"
>   ConentLength=250830 ETag=.... LastModified=...

**debugger demo_mask_download_data properties:**

> AcceptRange="bytes" Body=Uint8Array[5918] ContentType="JPG"
>   ConentLength=5918 ETag=.... LastModified=...

I have somehow to convert the downloaded image data to a file in order to be able to use it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the .mask() has a bug buffered data, so I'm just kind of allowed to use local file paths like .mask('../imgs/demo_mask.png'). 
For now I'm getting around this bug by using [tmp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp) module to create a temporary file of the s3 mask image.

This solves it for now